# RaisePropertyChanged doesn't update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

RaisePropertyChanged doesn't update the listbox in the UI after it is called.
Initially when the application is opened the update happens and the list is populated. After I call the constructor of the ViewModel (TracksVM) which triggers the method that updates the ObservableCollection the setter populates the collection but the RaisePropertyChanged seems to not have effect on the box.

**Solved:**
As suggested by Clemens I had 2 instances of the ViewModel class hence the listbox was not able to take the newly created list of Tracks as the new list was being past to the second instance. Once I ran the updating code on the same object instance the Listbox started to update accordingly.
XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="DownloadsBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrack}" Margin="10,10,10,10" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="TracksListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TracksVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private FileManager fm;
    private ObservableCollection<Track> _tracks;

    public ObservableCollection<Track> Tracks
    {
        get => _tracks;
        set
        {
            _tracks = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Tracks");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _genres;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Genres
    {
        get => _genres;
        set { _genres = value;  RaisePropertyChanged("Genres"); }
    }
    private Track _selectedTrack;
    public Track SelectedTrack
    {
        get => _selectedTrack;
        set
        {
            _selectedTrack = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTrack");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public TracksVM()
    {
        fm = new FileManager();
        LoadData();
    }
    void LoadData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading Tracks in Download box");
        Tracks = fm.ListOfTracks(ConfigurationManager.DownloadsDirectory).ToObservableCollection();
        Genres = ConfigurationManager.Genres.ToObservableCollection();
    }
}
```

The triggering of the ViewModel and respectively the update of the ObservableCollection:

```
 TracksVM tVM;
 internal void MoveTrack(string fileTobeMoved,string folderLocation)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"Track: {fileTobeMoved}, location: {folderLocation}");
        try
        {

            File.Move(fileTobeMoved, folderLocation);
            tVM = new TracksVM();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show more details as to how you set your view model to your window/control? Do you use a `Binding` or just do `DataContext = new VM()`?

Comment: You're creating a new TracksVM. Do you also assign this new instance to the DataContext of the view?

Comment: @PhilippeParé - Forgot to mention that, so - ` TracksVM mdVM;  mdVM = new TracksVM(); TracksTab.DataContext = mdVM;`

Comment: @Clemens - I think this is the root of the problem as I don't assign any new data context to the tab in which resides the listbox

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Clemens I had 2 instances of the ViewModel class hence the listbox was not able to take the newly created list of Tracks as the new list was being past to the second instance. Once I ran the updating code on the same object instance the Listbox started to update accordingly.